# In My add_post xml three imageviews are there camera,video,file on click of each imageview i want to open new dialogue box

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-linearlayout

In My add_post.xml, there are three imageviews camera,video,file `onClick` of each imageview i want to open new dialogue box

**add_post.xml**

```
  floatingActionButton= (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabId);
  floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService
                    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_post, null, false);
  builder  .setPositiveButton("Post", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            });

 builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new 

 DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {


                }
            });
            builder.setView(ll);
            builder.show();
```

imageView1= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgId);

```
            imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener                   

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                    // Include dialog.xml file
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_post);
                    // Set dialog title
                    dialog.setTitle("dialog");

                    dialog.show();

 }
```

Comment: Paste ur full code here

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dialog on each imageview clicklistner 
// Create custom dialog object

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
    // Include dialog.xml file
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    // Set dialog title
    dialog.setTitle("dialog");       

    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank u sir,but its showing me null pointer exception for imageview even if i found id for each imageview